# Do I need account-based permissions to initialize an mssoap client from a wsdl file?

Tags: soap, asp-classic, soap-client

I'm getting the this error when I try to use an ASP.NET WebService through an MSSOAP Client:

"WSDL Reader: Loading of the WSDL file failed  HRESULT=0X80040154 Class not registered - Client: An 
unanticipated error occured during the processing of this request.HRESULT=0x1812040:Class not registered."

At first I thought the SOAP library was not properly registered. But when I debugged the code I realized the error was being raised at the time of reading the web service definition (The Soap client does get created).

SOAPClient.mssoapinit "wsdl_URL"

Now, the issue only occurs when I execute the code as certain account (as for the rest of the accounts the code works pretty well). The original client is a Classic ASP page but I've reproduced the problem using a vbs script.

I run the script under several accounts, but just one presents the wsdl-reading failure.

- I've granted reading permissions to the directory that contains the
  asmx file to the failing account.
- I've changed the physical path of the virtual directory where the
  webservice is hosted to a general non-particular-profile location
  like C:.
- Ironically the application pool identity of the web application is
  the account that presents the failure.
- All the accounts can read the wsdl file through a browser just typing
  the url (but still one of them can't from client code)

Do I need to grant additional permissions for the account in order to read the web service definition and initialize the soap client?